Android 4 recovery: /udisk/ vs. /sdcard/ directory
I've got an Android 4.1-based device (PlayJam GameStick) whose official firmware updates had two files:

Update.img
factory_update_param.aml

The factory_update_param.aml contains instructions to automatically install the img file:
--update_package=/udisk/GameStick-Software-v2071.img

Copying those two files to SD card and booting into recovery leads to a "aborting finding installation package" (from my mind, probably worded a bit different).
In recovery, the .img file was available in the /sdcard/ folder and not /udisk/.
What is the /udisk/ folder? How can I get files to appear in there?

By trial an error I found out that the recovery's internal system has different folders for USB and SD:

/sdcard/ for updates on the SD card
/udisk/ for updates on USB flash drive

